# How can i sync users from ldap to joomla?

Tags: ldap, joomla

I have linux server with samba and openldap. I need to sync users data from openldap to joomla. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sync or authenticate?  Why not have Joomla do its auth against LDAP?  Getting passwords out of an existing system is rarely easy or doable.

Comment: Sync. Actually i don't need password data.

Comment: JMapMyLDAP is a great tool to sync users from LDAP to Joomla http://shmanic.com/tools/jmapmyldap
And you can use AD Explorer to make neccesart mapping configurations
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963907.aspx